# monitoring z3 memory usage characteristics

Tags: z3

I have some constraints which z3 takes a long time to solve. I am aware of the "-st" command-line flag that prints statistics but at the very end, and the TRACE facility for printing out internal data structure values. Is is there a way to get diagnostic information from within z3 (eg. to monitor memory usage continuously) as it is running (external tools like ps are not always convenient and do not always serve the purpose), when it is being used from the command-line? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `-v:100`, it sets the verbosity level to 100. It may not still display the memory usage as often as you want. 
Another option is to add the following line of code in appropriate places.

```
timeit tt(get_verbosity_level() >= 3, "report");
```

It will display memory usage if the verbosity level is `>= 3`.
For example, a good place is in the beginning of the method `lbool context::bounded_search()` at `src/smt/smt_context.cpp`. This method is executed after each restart.